# Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project that I started in `Java` on Android Studio and I want to continue it in `Kotlin`. So I configured my project to integrating Kotlin by this way "Configure Kotlin in Project"

[image]

After that Android Studio changed my twice `build.gradle` files. But from that moment my sync started to fail.

there is my `build.gradle` file where the error occurs :

**before** :

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**after :**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I get the following error :

> Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists.

When I remove the task clean I get the error :

> 1

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `task clean`? Most probably, the kotlin plugin added one.

Comment: yes I already tried, I got a so weird error that I will specify on my post.

Comment: just edited @Turing85

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After created a new Kotlin project and took a look about the `build.gradle` file

I adapted mine and it worked as well !

There is my current `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```